# what happens to background processes stdout and stderr when I log out?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to understand what happens with stdout and stderr of background processes when exiting an SSH session. I understand about SIGHUP, child processes and all that, but I'm puzzled about the following:

If I run:
(while true; do date; sleep 0.5; done) | tee foo | cat >bar
and then kill the cat process then the tee process terminates because it can no longer write into the pipe. You can observe this using ps.

But if I run:
(while true; do date; sleep 0.5; done) | tee foo & disown
and the log out of my SSH session, I can observe that everything continues running just fine "forever". So somehow the stdout of the tee process must "keep going" even though my pty must be gone.

Can anyone explain what happens in the second example?

(Yes, I know I could explicitly redirect stdout/stderr/stdin of the background process.)

Comment: You can inspect this yourself by looking at the `/proc/[pid]/fd` entries for the processes involved, or using `lsof -p [pid]` to get a better view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the crucial loop where `tee` sends output to stdout and opened files:

```
  while (1)
    {
      bytes_read = read (0, buffer, sizeof buffer);
      if (bytes_read < 0 && errno == EINTR)
        continue;
      if (bytes_read <= 0)
        break;

      /* Write to all NFILES + 1 descriptors.
         Standard output is the first one.  */
      for (i = 0; i <= nfiles; i++)
        if (descriptors[i]
            && fwrite (buffer, bytes_read, 1, descriptors[i]) != 1)
          {
            error (0, errno, "%s", files[i]);
            descriptors[i] = NULL;
            ok = false;
          }
    }
```

Pay closer attention on this part:

```
        if (descriptors[i]
            && fwrite (buffer, bytes_read, 1, descriptors[i]) != 1)
          {
            error (0, errno, "%s", files[i]);
            descriptors[i] = NULL;
            ok = false;
          }
```

It shows that when an error occurs, `tee` would not close itself but just unset the file descriptor `descriptors[i] = NULL` and continue to keep reading data until `EOF` or error on input occurs besides `EINTR`.

The `date` command or anything that sends output to the pipe connected to `tee` would not terminated since `tee` still reads their data. Only that the data doesn't go anywhere besides the file `foo`. And even if a file argument was not provided, `tee` would still read their data.

This is what `/proc/**/fd` looks like on `tee` when disconnected from a terminal:

```
0 -> pipe:[431978]
1 -> /dev/pts/2 (deleted)
2 -> /dev/pts/2 (deleted)
```

And this one's from the process that connects to its pipe:

```
0 -> /dev/pts/2 (deleted)
1 -> pipe:[431978]
2 -> /dev/pts/2 (deleted)
```

You can see that `tee`'s `stdout` and `stderr` is already EOL but it's still running.

Comment: Thanks for the details! This doesn't explain why tee exits in the first example (when cat is killed), does it?
Also, I have to cook up an example that doesn't use tee to see what happens to other processes that continue to write to the closed pty.

Comment: @TvE I find it similar since even if the pipe in front dies, `tee` would still run anyway.